How to fetch data from a database Laravel with Livewire?
I want to create a task which takes information from the clients table and makes a new record in the tasks table.
For example we take the client "Peter" and "Peter" has 4 objects "object_first", "object_second", "object_third" and "object_fourth". The idea is that we take that information and make a new record with it in the table tasks.
Here's the view:
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Create Task')

@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5 pd-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Create Task</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form wire:submit.prevent="saveTask">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <div class="col-md-5 mx-5">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                            <label for="clientId" class="fw-bold">Client*</label>
                                            <select wire:model="selectedClient" name="clientId" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="">Select client</option>
                                                @foreach ($clients as $client)
                                                    <option value="{{ $client->id }}">{{ $client->client }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                            @error('task.clientId')
                                                <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                        @if ($clientObjects)
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="Object1" class="fw-bold">Object Address 1*</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object1">
                                                @error('task.object1')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="object2">Object Address 2</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object2">
                                                @error('task.object2')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="object3">Object Address 3</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object3">
                                                @error('task.object3')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="object4">Object Address 4</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object4">
                                                @error('task.object4')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        @endif
                                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                            <label for="contractorId" class="fw-bold">Contractor*</label>
                                            <select name="contractorId" class="form-control"
                                                wire:model="selectedContractor">
                                                <option value="">Select contractor</option>
                                                @foreach ($contractors as $contractor)
                                                    <option value="{{ $contractor->id }}">{{ $contractor->contractor_name }}
                                                    </option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                            @error('task.contractorId')
                                                <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="d-flex gap-5">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                            <label for="certificateNumber" class="fw-bold">Certificate Number*</label>
                                            <input name="certificateNumber" type="text" class="form-control">
                                            @error('certificateNumber')
                                                <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                                            <label for="certificateDate" class="fw-bold">Certificate Date*</label>
                                            <input name="certificateDate" type="date" class="form-control">
                                            @error('certificateDate')
                                                <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <hr>
                                    <br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- vertical line-->
                                <div class="vr mx-5">&nbsp;</div>
                                <!-- vertical line-->
                                <div class="col-md-5 mx-5">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="d-flex gap-5">
                                            <div class="mb-3 pe-5">
                                                <label for="contractor_sum" class="fw-bold">Contractor Amount*</label>
                                                <input name="contractor_sum" type="number" class="form-control"
                                                    value="{{ $commissionPercentage }}">
                                                @error('contractor_sum')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ms-5 ps-5">
                                                <label for="total_sum" class="fw-bold">Total Amount Received (excl. VAT)*</label>
                                                <input name="total_sum" type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end">Add</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

and here's the Livewire component:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Tasks;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Clients;
use App\Models\Contragents;
use App\Models\Tasks;

class Create extends Component
{
    public $clients;
    public $contractors;
    public $selectedClient;
    public $selectedContragent;
    public $clientObjects = [];
    public $commissionPercentage;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->clients = Clients::all();
        $this->contractors= Contractors::all();
    }

    public $task = [
        'clientId' => '',
        'contractorId' => '',
        'object1' => '',
        'object2' => '',
        'object3' => '',
        'object4' => '',
    ];

    public function updatedSelectedClient($clientId)
    {
        $client = Clients::find($clientId);
        if ($client) {
            $this->clientObjects = [
                $client->object_first,
                $client->object_second,
                $client->object_third,
                $client->object_fourth
            ];
            $this->task['clientId'] = $clientId;
        }
    }

    public function updatedSelectedContractor($contractorId)
    {
        $contractors= Contractors::find($contragentId);
        if ($contractors) {
            $this->commissionPercentage = $contractor->commision_percentage;
            $this->task['contractorId'] = $contractorId;
        }
    }

    public function saveTask()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'task.clientId' => 'required',
            'task.contractorId' => 'required',
        ]);

        Tasks::create($this->task);

        session()->flash('message', 'Task created successfully!');
        return redirect()->to('pages/tasks');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.tasks.create')->layout('layouts.app');
    }
}

I tried with:
                                            @if ($clientObjects)
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="Object1" class="fw-bold">Object Address 1*</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object1">
                                                @error('task.object1')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="object2">Object Address 2</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object2">
                                                @error('task.object2')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="object3">Object Address 3</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object3">
                                                @error('task.object3')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                <label for="object4">Object Address 4</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="task.object4">
                                                @error('task.object4')
                                                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        @endif

but for some reason when the @if statement is present everything in it just doesn't show up and when it's absent the fields are present but no data is filled in the fields

@if ($clientObjects) must be removed otherwise, since $clientObjects is defaulted to an empty array in the class, it will never show task fields.
In any case there seems to be some data overlap: $clientObjects may not be necessary, since you are relying on the $tasks array for the form data.
When you say "when it's absent the fields are present but no data is filled in the fields", it's because you need to fill before the $tasks array in the class somewhere. I also see that there is a mismatch for   tags and there is one too many trailing .
